# How to find and see all my tweets?

Tags: twitter

Is there a way to find or index all my tweets on Twitter web or in Twitter app?

Comment: It's sad that we have to ask this, but as of today, I can't find my own tweets on twitter's site. You get bombarded with other people's tweets, but don't think you can select "Tweets" and simply see yours so to track any responses or go back to old tweets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login to your [Twitter](https://twitter.com) account. Look at left sidebar menu, click on `Profile` (on top of your profile header it shows your name and total number of tweets), now below your profile details there is a tab called `Tweets`, click on the `Tweets`, it will list the all your tweets (retweets). If you want to see replies also with tweets/retweets then click on `Tweets & replies` tab.

But in case you have a huge number of tweets and want check any particular tweet or very old tweet, you can use [Your Twitter archive](https://blog.twitter.com/2012/your-twitter-archive).

> Once you have your Twitter archive, you can view your Tweets by month, or search your archive to find Tweets with certain words, phrases, hashtags or @usernames. You can even engage with your old Tweets just as you would with current ones.

---

Some third party tools are also available to see all tweets and one of them is [All My Tweets](http://www.allmytweets.net/connect.php). (Please note I have not tested this tool.)

**Update:**

If you want to search and delete a tweet you can use [Advanced Search](https://twitter.com/search-advanced) feature of Twitter. Find a tweet and delete that.

Here is an [article](http://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/how-to-delete-old-tweets-now-your-whole-archive-is-sear-1661063579) also, you can read this, it will give you some help.

This can be done also by using Your Twitter archive, download your Twitter archive to your computer. You'll be given a HTML and CSV files that are even easier to search than the online interface. If you find any shameful tweets, you can switch to the Web versions to delete them.

---

In this case again you can use some third party tool like [TweetDeleter](http://www.tweetdeleter.com/en).(Not tested.)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I use Twitter app, and I know about "tweets" tab. But I have over 3000 tweets and I don't get to see all of them even if I keep scrolling. I thought about Twitter archive as well, but thing is I want to delete some or retweet old ones, in this case archival idea still doesn't help me.

Comment: Now you completed your question in comment.

Comment: @Sollosa: See update in answer, Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Sollosa: That's important information to include in your question. Comments are meant to be temporary, so please [update](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/82933/edit) your question.

Comment: Re. "in the home page below your profile pic there is a tab called TWEETS (it also shows the total number of tweets), click on the TWEETS, it will list the all your tweets (retweets).": Nope.  Don't see it.  Are you are only referring to the *mobile* vs. "Web" app?  Or maybe it's changed since 2015?

Comment: @Tom Here all answers are related to Web app only. Twitter UI has been changed, I have updated my answer accordingly. Hope you will be able to see it now.

Comment: Note that the second tab is now just "Replies" and contains the tweets sent to a specific person (starting with @username) although they are technically not replies.

Answer (score 0):

Your can use the twitter search tool for viewing old tweets for a specific date range. Use Twitter's advanced search. Advanced search lets you to search tweets from a specific user, in a particular time range.

Comment: thank you, a few examples would suffice though. Lets say I want to see my tweets from 2013. What would be the terms of searching? Is there a tweets searching guide available somewhere?

Comment: Head to https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=en .You can fill the "people" tab with your username and "Dates" with required day/month/year.

Comment: well in this case I have to open it in my browser, right? Or is advanced search feature available in android app too?

Comment: U can try using the keyword I guess..but I have not worked in it...

Comment: @parithi : I didn't see anything new in your answer.  About advance search and the link you have given in your comment, I have already mentioned in my answer. :)

Comment: @parithi: Can you [add the information](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/83022/edit) here in comments to your answer? But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today. Thanks in advance.